# Node.js Setup Wizard ended Prematurely on Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, windows-10

I tried to install Node.js Setup for the first time (`node-v8.9.1-x64` and `node-v9.2.0-x64`) on a system running Windows 10 64-bit , but it is giving the dreaded error

> Node.js Setup Wizard ended Prematurely

**Failed Attempts**

- Launching .msi from Command Prompt ran as Administrator
- Disabling the installation options

  - Performance Counters
  - Event Tracing
  - Online Document Shortcuts

[image]

**Registry Key Search**

No registry keys were found when running the following

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\_V2Providers\{793c9b44-3d6b-4f57-b5d7-4ff80adcf9a2}" /s
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\_V2Providers\{1e2e15d7-3760-470e-8699-b9db5248edd5}" /s
```

The installation log shows an error status: 1603. [[View Installation Log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e73e7033fc6e485275244e903370f0b)]

**Node is not installed**

```
node -v
```

Output:

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

**Attempt 3**

Tried the following based on [Github issue #4329](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4329#issuecomment-254825118), but theres no output after running this.

```
msiexec /i node-v8.9.1-x64.msi /qn+ ADDLOCAL=ALL REMOVE=NodePerfCtrSupport,NodeEtwSupport
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could have been asked on superuser instead?

Comment: @zerkms Saw these questions asked here on SO, but for earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: to me seems strange the attached log mentions `SHELL32` when you stated its a 64 bit box and you are installing a 64 bit nodejs app ... but then I know nothing about Windows boxes ... I will spin up a window box to do this myself

Comment: Sounds like a bug, so it might be more suitable to report a bug than to treat this as a programming question.